# Is there any better way to do this for loop?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.forms.listview

Good day, I have several pictures in my Xamarin Forms Project, I need to create a undefined number of textboxes, this should work like the user opens a XML file and it should deserialize it, create a textbox and add it to a page, if you add another, then it will be 2..

The issue here is that what should I do when the user gets Hundreds or even thousands of this textboxes, the app will crash?

So I want to ask if it there's a better way to improve my code, so the app loads normally, like a file explorer without lagging even with a lot of elements.

Like the Facebook app that handles undefined number of posts.

Following is the code for the loop:

```
foreach (string path in FileList)
{
    Textbox TB = new TextBox();
    //TBProperties
}
```

Comment: @TheGeneral It Was A Typo Mistake, I Already Fixed It

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just tried 1000 Entries in a ScrollView vs a ListView with 1000 items and an item template with a single Entry. The ListView is immensely more responsive because it's recycling the views.

```
XAML:

<ListView x:Name="lst"                  
        ItemsSource="{Binding Items}"
        CachingStrategy="RecycleElement"
        VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
        IsPullToRefreshEnabled="False"
        HasUnevenRows="False">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ViewCell>
                <Entry Text="{Binding Text}"></Entry>
            </ViewCell>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>

C#:

public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
    public class Item
    {
        public string Text { get; set; }
    }

    public List<Item> Items { get; set; }

    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();  
    }

    private void ContentPage_Appearing(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Items = new List<Item>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
        {
            Items.Add(new Item()
            {
                Text = Guid.NewGuid().ToString()
            });
        }
        lst.ItemsSource = Items;
    }
}
```

Comment: How long it took to load?

Comment: @Sergiobuenas 1000 Entries in a ScrollView took about 10 seconds to load on a modest tablet (~3 year old cheap Galaxy), and scrolling was choppy/lagging. The ListView didn't have any noticeable performance flaws. Scrolling was smooth. Definitely the way to go.